# R -fill matrix with pairs of simulated MVN data

Tags: r, matrix, simulation

I first want to simulate correlated MVN data using the mvrnorm function from the MASS package. Then I want to repeat this simulation i times and fill results in a matrix so that first results are in columns i, i+1, second in i+2, i+3 and so on.

So far I did the following:

```
    SimYCB <- c(73.1,60.6,59.6,54.5,57.9,61.14)
    SimPCB <- c(15.7,18.25,22.38,20.22,16.53,18.616)
    SimCB <- data.frame(SimYCB,SimPCB)
    n=20
    m=1000

    MVSimCB = matrix()
    for(i in 1:m)
    {MVSimCB[,i]=mvrnorm(n, mu=mean(SimCB),
               Sigma=cov(SimCB))}
```

What is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this helps

```
MVSimCB <- matrix(,ncol=m, nrow=n)
set.seed(24)
for(i in seq(1,m, by=2)){
  MVSimCB[, i:(i+1)] <- mvrnorm(n, mu=colMeans(SimCB), Sigma=cov(SimCB))
}
```

Or you could use `replicate`

```
set.seed(24)
MVSimCB2 <- do.call(cbind,  replicate(m/2, mvrnorm(n, mu=colMeans(SimCB), 
        Sigma=cov(SimCB)), simplify=FALSE))


all.equal(MVSimCB, MVSimCB2, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for. Now I understand the logic of it!